# DRY Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying to use ansible to manage roles for a remote postgres instance, with a playbook that looks like:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - postgresql_user:
      login_host: the.db.com
      login_password: password
      port: 5432
      login_user: admin
      db: the-db
      name: user-i-want-to-create
```

This works, but there are many such users I want to create, and repeating the 5 parameters over and over for each user is tedious and error-prone. How can I factor out those variables to not need to repeat them for each task?

Comment: I had a similar problem, and the answer from Ansible back then was "that's not what Ansible was designed to do". Not sure if things have changed over the past year.

Comment: Have you bothered to look at Ansible docs at all? Google `ansible loops`.

Comment: @techraf I had, but hadn't thought to search for loops specifically. They seem verys promising though, if not being quite what I was looking for. (They still require repeating connection info for different postgres related constructs, e.g.).

Answer (score 4):

This will work pretty easily with a couple of variables and a loop. Something like this should do it:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    pgsql_default_db: "the-db"
    pgsql_root_user: "admin"
    pgsql_root_pass: "password"
    pgsql_users:
      - name: "user_1"
        password: "user_1_password"
      - name: "user_2"
        password: "user_2_password"
      - name: "user_3"
        password: "user_3_password"
        db: "the-alternate-db"
  tasks:
    - name: Create database users.
      postgresql_user:
        login_host: the.db.com
        login_password: "{{ pgsql_root_pass }}"
        login_user: "{{ pgsql_root_user }}"
        port: 5432
        db: "{{ item.db | default(pgsql_default_db) }}"
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        password: "{{ item.password }}"
      with_items: "{{ pgsql_users }}"
```

This creates three users, defined by the `pgsql_users` var, and shows a way to vary some of the properties--`user_3` is created with access to a different database than `user_1` and `user_2`.

There's only *one* task now, so it's easy to set up, and with a little finagling, [the user data could even come from a different source](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/howto-looking-up-external-directories-in-ansible/) (though the data structure would need to be similar to what I've shown here in order to use the basic `with_items` loop).